# git push error . bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

Tags: bash, git, syntax, token, newline

I want to push changes to github:

`$ git push origin <add-fata-branch>`

the following error message is printed:

`` bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline' ``

Comment: remove brackets and just use `git push origin add-fata-branch`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're using unquoted angle brackets. If your branch is called `add-fata-branch`, then you should write `git push origin add-fata-branch` without the angle brackets. If your branch is really called `<add-fata-branch>` (which is not recommended), you must put quotation marks around it: `git push origin "<add-fata-branch>"`.

If you're reading a guide, be aware that the angle brackets are designed to indicate a placeholder and shouldn't be typed literally.